# How to get table data from google docs to google spreadsheet?

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have around 40-50 google docs in each of them there are tables which I need to get to the  Spreadsheet.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5P1t4.png)

As you can see in the image above Particulars column is same for all the docs.
I need the data from those sheets in below format

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nDK9.png)

I have tried to do this in google apps script but being a beginner I can't find a way to get this automated.

Please help me do this.

I tried using google-apps-script with the help of chatgpt but failed also tried to get to make it work with the help of python and using google-api.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to programmatically copy data from Google Docs to Google Sheets. If yes, the answer is simultaneously simple and complex - the instruction is straightforward but not a code (moreover, my experience tells me that Google will give you a hard time with authentication).

#### API

To access both documents, you can use the API repository provided by Google. Here you can find a list of all the supported languages:
https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/cloud-client-libraries
And since the question was asked in the Python category, you can install it directly from PIP:
`pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage`
(source: https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/setup)

But here, simple things are getting more complex.

First, you need to authenticate yourself with the option most suitable for your needs. I would recommend starting here:
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication

Here, you will find code snippets for extracting data from docs:
https://developers.google.com/docs/api/samples/extract-text

Here, you will find instructions on how to write data into a sheet:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values

#### Workaround

Regarding the above explanation, using it would be overkill for your task, and you may want to use some workarounds. If tasked with such a thing, I would gather every file in one driver directory, download it, then use Python to enumerate all docs to fetch data from it, and then - with Pandas library - I would insert/join data into sheets. Then, I would replace sheets with new ones. It sounds like a manual task you are not asking for, but it will be less time-consuming than a connection to Google API.